# VSCode Unable to locate phpcs on macOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, phpcs

I know this has been asked many times but I can't find an answer that works for me. I'm on a Mac running macOS **10.15.6** and I'm getting the issue of **Unable to locate phpcs** in VSCode version **1.47.3**. The actual error is:

```
phpcs: Unable to locate phpcs. Command failed: "/Users/mat/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs" --version
```

If I run `/Users/mat/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs --version` in my terminal I get the correct response and if I do `which phpcs` I get the desired /Users/mat/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs.

When I switch the VSCode extension works as it should but then when I close and reopen VSCode I get the error, which is solved again if I switch extensions.

My VSCode settings are:

```
"phpcs.enable": true,
"php.validate.executablePath": "/Users/mat/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs",
"phpcs.executablePath": "/Users/mat/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs",
"phpcs.standard": "PSR12",
```

I've really been unable to figure out why this error keeps happening when I launch VSCode. Any help would be greatly appricated.

Thanks

Comment: [Have you tried to put in an absolute path? That was the only way I was able to get it to work on my mac.](https://github.com/ikappas/vscode-phpcs/issues/175#issuecomment-671408874)?

Comment: Hi @zrzka thanks for replying. I have added the path to PHPCS in my settings.json but still get the error. I've updated my question to so my settings

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have the same issue on mac, I've copied the output of which phpcs in to the path for user config "phpcs: executable path" but it says it can't find it.